# Ceph-ansible adding new OSD disk

Tags: storage, ceph

I need some help in adding a new OSD disk to the existing Ceph cluster using Ceph-Ansible deployment, I have 3 OSD hosts and want to add one disk to 1st OSD host, I tried to include the new disk in the osd.yml file under devices section, but I got failed deployment cause ansible return an error that it cannot find the included new disk in 2nd and 3rd OSD host.

Is there a way to tell ceph-ansible to include new disk /dev/sde for instance to only 1st OSD host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `devices` variable to the `host_vars` of your first node.
If you have an inventory directory you can add `host_vars` directory in your inventory directory and add a file with your hostname in your hosts. For example if you have node1 in your `hosts.yaml` you should create a file named `node1.yaml` in `host_vars` directory and add `devices` variable in it so this variable is just used for this host.
You can find more info about `host_vars` here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables

Comment: Thanks Seena, that what exactly what m looking for